# is jquery on() always better than bind()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've read the posts of `live()` versus `delegate()` versus `on()`, and understand the position.

I also understand how `click()` is just a shortcut for `on()`, and how the two statements are identical.

```
$( "#clickTarget" ).click(function() {alert( "Handler for .click() called." );});
$( "#onTarget" ).on('click',function() {alert( "Handler for .on() called." );});
```

My question is whether there is any advantage of using `bind()` over `on()`?  Note that the documentation states *"As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document."* For instance, if my element exists upon writing of the DOM, it seems to make sense.  If so, is there a shortcut version of `bind()` which binds on click?

```
$( "#bindTarget" ).bind( "click", function() {alert( "Handler for .bind() called" );});
```

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in .on() or .delegate()."

- jQuery documentation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/d1f247daf82e9b123690f8f51c7b3d1818bccbfe/src/event/alias.js#L23) :

```
bind: function( types, data, fn ) {
    return this.on( types, null, data, fn );
},
```

As you see, `bind` just calls `on`. There's NO reason to use `bind`. Never.